# How can I make mdadm auto-assemble RAID after each boot?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, home-server, kubuntu, mdadm

I successfully created a RAID (mirroring) by utilizing `mdadm`. However, I must run the following commands after each boot:

```
mdadm --stop --scan // to stop /dev/md127 - I don't know where the number 127 even comes from
mdadm --assemble --scan // to start /dev/md0
```

What am I doing wrong/why do I need to run these commands at boot? What is the right way to auto-start RAID with each (re)boot?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**NB: You either need to be logged in as root, or use *sudo* to do all this...**

- Use your favourite editor to create or edit */etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf* file as follows:

If the file does not even exist, paste the following into the new, empty file:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
```

- Save the file
- Run the following command to add a reference to your array config at the end of the file:

  *mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf*

This should add a line like the following to the end of mdadm.conf:

> ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5
>   num-devices=3 metadata=00.90
>   UUID=a44a52e4:0211e47f:f15bce44:817d167c

If the mdadm command has added any other stuff above the ARRAY line, remove it. For example, on one of my machines, the command returns 'mdadm: metadata format 00.90 unknown, ignored.' before the ARRAY line.

Your array should now auto-build on boot and thus you can add an entry to /etc/fstab to mount it (if it's not already there)

Comment: I would maybe add: you should also update your initramfs with `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: mdadm --detail --scan does not print anything on my system, although I know for sure that I have two partitions that are part of a raid0 (mirror). Any general advice on this is welcome.

Comment: @LennartRolland - try `mdadm -Es` instead.

Comment: this did not work for me, I had to do `grub-install /dev/sda` to make it work (replace sda for anything appropriate for you)

Comment: Alternatively you can just use the kernel option: *`md.auto=1`* ... I haven't actually tested this thoroughly but supposedly it detects them and assembles them (or at least tries to do so). But then https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/md.html is a bit ambiguous on that: *When md is compiled into the kernel (not as module), partitions of type 0xfd are scanned and automatically assembled into RAID arrays. [...] As of kernel 2.6.9, only drives with a type 0 superblock can be autodetected and run at boot time.* And it doesn't refer to md.auto (or whatever it was) so I'm not sure now.

Comment: Just another sidenote, which took us two days to figure out: Disks must have a UUID before creating the RAID, otherwise the created IDs will change and the RAID won't be assembled. So we 1.) formated the individual disks, 2.) created the mdadm raid 3.) formatted the raid 4.) mounted the raid 5.) configured the raid to auto-mount it on startup

Comment: Change `metadata=00.90` to `metadata=0.90`

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is an older question, but I had a frustrating time with this on the 32-bit version of Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Running `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` appended the line

> ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=ubuntu:0 UUID=a8a570c6:96f61865:05abe131:5c2e2f7e

After a reboot I could never see /dev/md0. Running the `mdadm --detail --scan` again (without putting the result in a file) I would see

> ARRAY /dev/md/ubuntu:0 metadata=1.2 name=ubuntu:0 UUID=a8a570c6:96f61865:05abe131:5c2e2f7e

and manually mounting `/dev/md/ubuntu:0` would work. In the end, that was what I put in the fstab file too.

I am not sure what I got wrong, if this is how it works in Ubuntu 12.04, or if this is a bad practice. Just wanted to share what worked for me.

Comment: Same "problem" here. Not sure if it is a problem, though..

Comment: On reboot my device had changed from `/dev/md0` to `/dev/md127`

Comment: @Soth: You probably forgot to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` before rebooting.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem on my Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). I had a RAID array on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` which failed to assemble at boot. I had in my `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file the entry

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=53454954:4044eb66:9169d1ed:40905643 name=raspberrypi:0
```

(your numbers will be different; see other answers on how to get this.)

I had in my `/etc/fstab` file the entry

```
/dev/md0        /data           ext4    defaults          0       0
```

(and of course `/data` indeed existed)

Like the OP, I could assemble and mount the RAID array by hand after boot, but I could not get it to happen automatically during boot despite apparently correctly setting it up.

I was able to solve the problem as follows. I investigated the script at `/etc/init.d/mdadm-raid` and inserted a line of debug code

`ls /dev > /home/pi/devices.txt`

Rebooting and checking this file I learned that devices `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` existed at the time the `mdadm-raid` initialization happened, but the partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` were missing. I edited the `/etc/init.d/mdadm-raid` file and inserted the line

`partprobe`

after the header (i.e. after the `### END INIT INFO` but before the script begins). This caused the partitions to be detected and so the `mdadm-raid` script was able to assemble the RAID array, resolving the problem. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

On Debian wheezy one more step is required:
in `/etc/default/mdadm` set *autostart* from false to true

```
#AUTOSTART:
#   should mdadm start arrays listed in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf automatically
#   during boot?
AUTOSTART=true
```

Also I had to use `mdadm -Es >>/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` instead of the `--scan` option, as that did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo mdadm -Es >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Now edit lines added to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf in the following way. Delete everything, but the basic parts. It should look like

```
ARRAY /dev/md5 UUID=031cea92:50a7a28c:6b077fe7:8817092a
ARRAY /dev/md6 UUID=53454954:4044eb66:9169d1ed:40905643
```

*Note: you can choose X in mdX to your convenience.*

Now reboot

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

*EDIT: command corrected.*

Comment: I wrote thi because Linker3000's answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with this on Raspbian using a couple of external USB HDD's on a Raspberry Pi. I had to mess with the start order of services to make sure that mdadm-raid started after the USB drives were recognised by udev but before checkfs.sh (which checks filesystems at boot time). If mdadm-raid started too early, the drives were not available and therefore the array was not assembled. That meant that fsck subsequently failed and the boot process dropped out to a maintenance prompt (because the raid array is required for other services).

Modifying boot dependencies to start mdadm-raid after checkroot.sh but before checkfs.sh and running `update-rc.d mdadm-raid defaults`, followed by `` update-initramfs -uv -k `uname -r` `` (note backticks around `uname`) fixed it (finally). For me, anyway, YMMV.

Comment: Note that uname -r in the above is supposed to be in back-ticks but I can't figure out how to escape them so they're printed here...

Comment: Which version of raspbian was this? I had it working fine on Wheezy, but ugrading to Jessie broke the assemble on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Having the Raspberry Pi 3, adding the `rootdelay=5` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` solved this problem for me.

The credit goes [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=153578).

Answer (score -1):

I tried with

`mdadm --create /dev/md/abcdef ...`

I see the softlink `/dev/md/abcdef` persisting on reboots and if need be access the device through soft link.

Is it a acceptable solution ?