# Linux mdadm does not assemble array, but recreation of array does it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, raid-1, mdadm

Maybe i'm not very clear in the title. When i'm trying to assemble my raid1 array with mdadm:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

It tells me that

```
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sdc has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

If i reorder devices in command:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc
```

It tells the same for `sdd`:

```
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdd has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Here's some info about drives:

```
➜  ~ sudo mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdc 
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
➜  ~ sudo mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

But! When i'm recreating array with

```
➜  ~ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdc appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 07:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdc but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
mdadm: /dev/sdd appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 07:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdd but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
Continue creating array? yes
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

Instead of making the new array, it starts my array!

```
➜  ~ ls -l /dev/mapper/MisakaMirror-alldata 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 май 19 01:48 /dev/mapper/MisakaMirror-alldata -> ../dm-2
```

But i want to achieve this with

```
mdadm --assemble
```

To do it automatically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resolution

> ℝℕℕ:
>   The instructions below **delete** your existing RAID setup and create a new md RAID 1 array with two entire block devices, `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`.

1. Ensure that your kernel has the RAID 1 md module loaded with either of these commands:

   ```
   lsmod | grep 'raid1\s'
   grep 'Personalities : .*\[raid1\]' /proc/mdstat
   ```
2. If you do not get an output above, load the RAID 1 md module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe raid1
   ```
3. Make md forget your existing corrupt array by zapping the disks:

   ```
   sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdc
   sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdd
   ```

   Note that `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sd{c,d}` might not operate if `mdadm` doesn't detect an existing array properly.
4. Recreate your RAID 1 array using the entire devices `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`:

   ```
   sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
   ```
5. To make the new array assemble automatically, add the contents of the following command to the bottom of your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file:

   ```
   sudo mdadm --detail --scan
   ```

   <sup><sub>See also: [How can I make mdadm auto-assemble RAID after each boot?](https://superuser.com/a/287510/83694)</sub></sup>

---

### Explanation

Your two `mdadm --misc -E` commands reveal that `mdadm` is not seeing the metadata for your RAID devices.  Your example:

```
➜  ~ sudo mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdc 
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

It looks like `/dev/sdc` has a partition `/dev/sdc1`.  If you're using a whole device as the md RAID device, you would not have `/dev/sdc1`.  (The same goes for your `/dev/sdd`.)

Furthermore, when you try recreating the array, `mdadm` detects this strange information:

```
mdadm: /dev/sdc appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 07:00:00 1970
```

You're trying to use RAID 1 with two devices today, but `mdadm` reports RAID 0 with no devices at [epoch 0](http://www.epochconverter.com/?source=searchbar&q=00000000).  This is clearly not right.

Maybe at some point you tried creating an array on `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdd1` (the partitions) rather than on `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` (the entire devices), and the md superblocks got muddled while you struggled to figure out the issue.

For this reason, I believe that you should zap the disks and start over.